# Visual Studio 2010 - C# UserControl event firing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, events, user-controls

I'm attempting to make a grid based dungeon system at the moment in Visual Studio 2010. I have a main user control which contains 64 other smaller user control objects, which I've called GridSquares, organised into an 8x8 grid. The idea behind the grid squares is to act as potential movement spaces within the 'dungeon'. The problem I have at the moment is that I need to be able to call a click event on the user controls (GridSquares) themselves, which have been placed on screen so I can retrieve their coordinate (name) for comparison. However the event does not work when I call it (through clicking).

I am aware that the events work when I place them within the usercontrol (GridSquare object) but I need the click even to work when the user control itself is clicked.

Given that all 64 objects placed are the same type I can not work within the GridSquare class as I require the name of the user control to be returned through the event.

I hope this makes sense but please ask if I need to explain further.

Many thanks, Liam

EDIT:
I'm not sure how much this will help or what code to display but the GridSpace controls have already been added to the 'dungeon' user control. Then within I add all 64 to a dictionary:

```
gridSpaces.Add(gs11.Name, gs11);
```

Where gs11 is the name of the GridSquare.

From here I tried creating event handlers for the individual user controls on the dungeon screen, which failed to call.

Comment: I am using Windows Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i get what your saying. Add this code to your user control:

```
public new event EventHandler Click {
    Add {
        base.Click += value;
        foreach(Control i in Controls) {
            i.Click+=value;
        }
    }
    remove {
        base.Click -= value;
        foreach(Control i in Controls) {
            i.Click -= value;
        }
    }
    }
```

this will add the click event to everything in your user control, i hope i didnt make any errors, and that this helps

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. It does exactly what I need it to do. Thank you very much

Comment: no problem :) i ran into the exact same problem when I was making custom buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same handler for each `GridSquare` and use the `sender` parameter to decide which one was clicked:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
   {
      GridSquare square = new GridSquare();
      square.Click += new EventHandler(gridSquare_Click);
      grid.Add(gridSquare);
   }
}

void gridSquare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridSquare square = (GridSquare)sender;
   // do something cool with the clicked square here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem is that the main user control does not register the click event on the actual grid square objects, only what is inside of them.

Comment: @Lazz, sounds like a good time to add some of your code to the question. :)